# How to add web requests to queue using celery?

Tags: django, celery

I have integrated django-celery-beat which is working fine that means i can register and execute task after some interval of time. But what my client want is to queue up web requests. That means, for example if two users come on the website and both wants to generate a report then second user request will go into queue and wait for the completion of first request.

I am not sure whether this is possible with celery. I have tried to find solution but no success. Can anyone help me regarding this. I just need idea or some sample script. Thanks

Comment: If you send that request into a queue and force your client to wait until it's finished. That's a huge problem for your system and for the UX of your customers too. Some how you should send task message into celery and just let celery handle that task. With your user, you could provide them a page to check that the task finished or not (django-celery does allow this) and from there they can download exported report

Answer (score 0):

This is quite possible with celery.  You can force certain reports to a particular [routing exchange](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) and then map that routing exchange / celery queue to a particular celery worker using the `-Q` flag and then set the worker to only consume one task at a time.  It take a little bit of work and a little bit of config, but it can be done. 
 Make sure to use the [correct settings for reserving one task at a time](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#reserve-one-task-at-a-time).